# iOS - Wait for a query to be completed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table that displays the results of an http request.
Sometimes the application crashes because the table is displayed before the query is finished .. How can the application no crash?

The table :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MyCustomCell
        for i in 0...nameOfRoutesStart.count {
            if (indexPath.row == i) {
                cell.originLabel.text = nameOfRoutesStart[i]
                cell.destinationLabel.text = nameOfRoutesEnd[i]
                let id = driver[i]
                self.userTasks.user(driverId: id, completionHandler: { (status, success) -> Void in
                    if success {
                        cell.driverLabel.text = self.userTasks.username
                    }
                })
                cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I make the request in another function
Thanks

Comment: **You should not run asynchronous functions inside `cellForRowAt`.** Instead, run the function, wait for it to fill up your data source and then reload the table view.

Comment: for loop in cellforRowAtIndexPath...avoid it. Make request for only cells which are visible on view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract your asynchronous code from the tableview methods to your viewDidLoad. Save the data you retrieve in a variable declared in your controller and call .reloadData() on your tableview when your fetch is finished.

Comment: Ok, thanks
How can I wait for the query to execute before executing other rows in the ViewDidLoad. Because the code runs before the query is finished, and so it does not work ..

Comment: Your query must have a completion handler, which is called when the query is completed and gives you either the data or the error returned to your app. You should create your data and reload your interface at this moment.